# Comment upvote triangle always appears "upvoted"?

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, comment-voting

[image]

See the image, I haven't voted up [this comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/200974/how-to-manually-remove-an-app#comment257042_200980), but the triangle inclined me into thinking I've voted.

Chrome 68.0.3440.91 from Google Play on OnePlus 6 running Android 8.1.

Comment: Can't reproduce for Android 7. Moreove upvoted triangle color is [brown in mobile web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA7Q2.png) for me.

Comment: @alexolut I'm on Android.SE (main site).

Comment: I would expect to see the flag icon as well but that is missing from your screenshot. Are you sure no stylescripts or userscripts are messing with your DOM?

Comment: @rene mobile site doesn't have a flag button for comment.

Comment: @rene This question is tagged [tag:mobile-web]. On desktop there's a flag icon.

Comment: Still can't reproduce on Android.SE. But if I revoke upvote for a comment I will see the same as in your picture. BTW upvoted comment has a number on mobile (even when upvoted only once).

Comment: @alexolut I didn't upvote and remove, just not touched it at all.

Comment: fair enough but still no repro for me

Comment: Maybe your BUG part touched it :)

Comment: @alexolut it's not the upvoted color, it's the "active" color when you just tap it

Comment: @ShadowtheWelcomingWizard which one? BTW when I mention you in comment there is no need to add extra characters before send anymore :)

Comment: @alexolut dunno, I saw the blue when clicking the arrow, then after that it became brown as you said. And yeah, my name is now long. ;)

Comment: Reproduced (Chrome 56.0.2924.87 from Google Play, phone running Android 5.1). Happens on two questions where I had "full" activity (edited the Q, commented, and answered): [instance 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KeZM.png) and [instance 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHxd7.png). Does not happen where I only edited and commented ([instance 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG9OO.png)) nor where I had zero activity ([instance 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zNDH.png))

Comment: Same problem on two comments under [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/200983/205764). I'm the author of the answer and also edited the question.

Comment: Same bug reported on [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/unvoted-on-comments-look-voted-on).