# "comment shorter than 15" notification is blocked and makes the whole answer scrollable

Tags: bug, comments, design, mobile-web, notification-bar

[image]

See the pale yellow "box" below the "Add Comment" button. Y'all know it's the "comment must have at least 15 characters" notification, and it's just cut in half and no readable text is shown.

Plus, the "dismiss" button is slightly visible (its top border)

[image]

Note: this is triggered when you enter more than 15 characters in the comment box **of an answer**, but after compacting (continuous and leading/trailing spaces) it is too short.

Plus, when such bug happens, the whole answer becomes scrollable:

[image]

Chrom 69.0.3497.100 on Android 8.1.

Comment: hmm... Which site? Which post are you trying to comment on? Using Chrome 69 on Android 7.1 with this question, I get the full error.

Comment: @Shog9 Right here MSE, any answer.

Comment: This must be your punishment for getting to run 8.1 then. Or I'm doing it wrong. If anyone else can reproduce, post steps please...

Comment: Ok, I see it now. Gotta be an answer, ideally not the last answer on the page

Comment: @Shog9 See the updated post.

Comment: Thanks for upvoting my comment :)

Comment: @Sonic https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314862/350567